# Чем отличается import от require при сборке webpack-ом

Tags: javascript, webpack

Хотел узнать в чем различия между import-ом и required в javascript. Например, у нас есть два подключения

```
import './components';
require('./helpers');
```

В чем их разница? Буду благодарен за развернутый ответ или ссылку на ресурс где можно прочесть.
Собираю проект webpack-ом, если это имеет значение

Comment: Предпологаю при require скрипт должен загрузится в любом случае а при import необязательно

Comment: @Duoxx а можно поподробней, пожалуйста?Или ссылку на ресурс где можно об этом почитать

Comment: При require `'./helpers'` должен подключится в любом случае иначе скрипт не заработает. При import  `'./components'` может и не загрузится но работать будет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export

Answer (score 0):

`import` может быть асинхронен:

```
const module = await import('module');
```

`import` позволяет грузить части модуля:

```
import {foo, bar} from "module";
```

Подробности [тута](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html).

Comment: _`import` может быть асинхронен:_ - `require` тож

Comment: @Grundy  давно ?

Comment: я про [вот это](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#code-splitting-with-es2015)

Answer (score 0):

Что касается конкретно вебпака то плюс от `import/export` будет заключатся в возможности tree shacking (уменьшении объема бандлов)
[подробнее в документации](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

- [немного устаревшая статья но объясняющая суть tree shacking](https://insights.untapt.com/webpack-import-require-and-you-3fd7f5ea93c0)

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, выпилил

Answer (score 0):

1. `import`:

   - `import` - это стандартный синтаксис ES6 для импорта модулей.
   - Он использует статический анализ, что означает, что импорты резолвятся во время компиляции.
   - `import` поддерживает динамические импорты, которые позволяют загружать модули асинхронно во время выполнения программы.
   - `import` также позволяет импортировать только определенные экспорты из модуля с помощью фигурных скобок `{}`.
   - Пример использования `import`:

     ```js
     import React from 'react';
     ```
2. `require`:

   - `require` - это синтаксис CommonJS, который используется в старых версиях JavaScript и Node.js.
   - Он использует динамическое выполнение, что означает, что импорты резолвятся во время выполнения программы.
   - `require` не поддерживает динамические импорты.
   - `require` позволяет импортировать весь модуль целиком.
   - Пример использования `require`:

     ```js
     const React = require('react');
     ```

При использовании Webpack, вы можете использовать оба синтаксиса `import` и `require` в вашем проекте. Webpack будет обрабатывать эти импорты и создавать соответствующие зависимости между модулями в вашем собранном проекте.

Однако, при использовании современных версий JavaScript и сборке с помощью Webpack, рекомендуется использовать синтаксис `import`, так как он является стандартом ES6 и предоставляет более удобный и гибкий способ импорта модулей.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)